# How to write a Julia function that passes an arbitrary number of arguments to another function?

Tags: julia, variadic-functions

I'm new to Julia and much more experienced in R, so for those who are familiar with both, here is a snippet of R code that I'm trying to replicate in Julia.

```
f = function(a, b = 1, c = 2) a + 2*b = 3*c
g = function(d, ...) 5 + f(d, ...)
```

With this it would be valid to call `g(1)`, which would evaluate with the default values for f, or you could specify `g(1, b = 3)` or `g(1, c = 4, b = 2)`, or whatever. The point is of course that you can pass any permutation of optional arguments to f without order mattering as long as the names are specified.

In Julia I've had a bit of trouble doing this because the varargs stuff works a bit differently. I'm aware that you can pass an unlimited list of arguments to a function in the form of a tuple (e.g., `function g(d::Number, f_args::NamedTuple`), but it seems like it doesn't work with optional keyword arguments. It's almost as if somewhere along the line the `f_args` tuple loses its names, and `f` gets confused because it sees 3 arguments without names and doesn't know which method to select?

If it is indeed possible, I'd really appreciate if someone could show me how to do this in Julia. I would like to preserve the optionality of these arguments, as well as their names. I'd also like to be able to keep their types (i.e., I'd like each argument of `f` to only be acceptable if they fit under the correct type, which is of course usually done in Julia with the `::` operator in the header).

PS - for the purposes of my question, rewriting `g` so it has `c` and `b` as optional arguments will not suffice for me. I display the example of `f` and `g` for simplicity but in reality am hoping to apply these principles to much more complex functions with many arguments.

Answer (score 8):

In julia, optional positional arguments and keyword arguments are treated differently.

If we want to allow arbitrary argument order in a function, we have to specify [keyword arguments](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Keyword-Arguments).  Unlike in R, julia insists that we differentiate between positional arguments and keyword arguments using a semicolon in the argument list.  We can write your functions `f` and `g` in julia to allow this by simply adding appropriate semicolons:

```
f(a; b=1, c=2) = a + 2*b + 3*c
g(d; kwargs...) = 5 + f(d; kwargs...)
```

This defines a method `f` with one required positional argument and two optional keyword arguments, and another method `g` with one required positional argument and [any number of keyword arguments](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Varargs-Functions) that will be passed on to `f`. That means we can do:

```
g(1)             # 14
g(1) == 5 + f(1) # true
g(1, b=3)        # 18
g(1, c=4, b=2)   # 22
```

Again, unlike in R, keyword arguments are different from positional arguments, so we cannot do this:

```
f(1, 2, 4)
# ERROR: MethodError: no method matching f(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64)
# Closest candidates are:
#   f(::Any; b, c) at REPL[1]:1
```

This is because the method signature we defined takes exactly one positional argument. If you want a function that can take either positional arguments or keyword arguments, we have to define a new function signature, like this:

```
f(a, x=1, y=2) = f(a; b=x, c=y)
```

Here, we are creating some new methods with the same name `f` as our original method, and all they do is pass on their positional arguments as keyword arguments.  Now we can do this:

```
f(1, 2, 4) == 17  # true
```

If we want `g` to function in a similar way, remembering that julia makes a distinction between positional and keyword arguments, we need to specify *two* varargs: one for the positional arguments and one for the keyword arguments:

```
g(d, args...; kwargs...) = 5 + f(d, args...; kwargs...)
```

Now we can do things like this:

```
g(1, 2) == g(1, b=2)         # true
g(1, 2, 4) == g(1, c=4, b=2) # true
```

But things get messy when we try to combine these types of signatures:

```
g(1, 2, c=4)
# ERROR: MethodError: no method matching f(::Int64, ::Int64; c=4)
# Closest candidates are:
#  f(::Any, ::Any) at REPL[18]:1 got unsupported keyword argument "c"
#  f(::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at REPL[18]:1 got unsupported keyword argument "c"
#  f(::Any; b, c) at REPL[18]:1
```

Why is this not allowed?  The error message gives us a hint as to what defining [optional positional arguments](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Optional-Arguments) do under the hood.  When we define a method with *n* optional positional arguments, julia just makes *n+1* methods, each with 0 through *n* arguments tagged on to the end of the signature. Like this:

```
h(a, b=1, c=2, d=3) = nothing
# h (generic function with 4 methods)

methods(h)
# 4 methods for generic function "h":
#[1] h(a) in Main at REPL[32]:1
#[2] h(a, b) in Main at REPL[32]:1
#[3] h(a, b, c) in Main at REPL[32]:1
#[4] h(a, b, c, d) in Main at REPL[32]:1
```

That means when we defined the optional positional argument version of `f`, julia made the signatures `f(a, b)` and `f(a, b, c)` for us, but it did *not* make a method with the signature `f(a, b; c)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the incredibly thorough explanation! I was missing that semicolon in the header of `g`. Very much appreciate you for taking the time to do this!